# How to execute the viewcomponent and read the viewcomponent's parameters from the controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, actionresult, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am using the below code to execute view component in .cshtml

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("FileUpload",Model)
```

Inside that view component, there is a file uploader.
[image]

After select a file when I click Upload button ( Upload button is also inside the viewcomponent) debug goes to controller. My controller's action goes like below

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ToolModel model)
        {
           
            model.FileUploadFileFormats = "application/pdf";
            model.FromFileType = FileTypes.pdf;
            model.ToFileType = FileTypes.doc;

           
            return View(FullPathsOfViews.PdfToWord, model);
        }
```

After executing above then next goes to Viewcomponent methods. After that coding path exits. Instead that I want to bring the result from viewcomponent back to the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ToolModel model)
        {
           
            model.FileUploadFileFormats = "application/pdf";
            model.FromFileType = FileTypes.pdf;
            model.ToFileType = FileTypes.doc;

           VAR Result = Component.InvokeAsync("FileUpload",Model) //Something like this

            return View(FullPathsOfViews.PdfToWord, model);
        }
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I couldn't understand why you want to call the Viewcomponent, if your Viewcomponent contains the specific logic, you could put it inside a specific method  and call it both inside the Viewcomponent and Index method

Comment: How to call a specific method in viewcomponent from the control's index method?

Comment: Build a method that both controller and viewcomponent call it.